# MVC Model Custom Control Attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am using custom uniqueemail confirmation attribute like

```
public class UniqueEmailAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        WMContext db = new WMContext();
        var userWithTheSameEmail = db.Users.SingleOrDefault(
            u => u.email == (string)value);
        return userWithTheSameEmail == null;
    }

}
```

It is working fine while inserting user. But, when I try to update user it gives an error.

```
public class User
{
    public int userID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    [UniqueEmail(ErrorMessage = "This email is used by another user")]
    public string email { get; set; }
}
```

Solution : I have changed the IsValid method like this :

```
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var model = (User)validationContext.ObjectInstance;
        WMContext db = new WMContext();
        var userWithTheSameEmail = db.Users.SingleOrDefault(
            u => u.email == (string)value && u.userID!=model.userID);
        if (userWithTheSameEmail!=null)
        {
            return new ValidationResult("Bu eposta adresi kullanılıyor.");
        }
        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
```

Comment: Please remove your solution from the question and place it as an answer, it is perfectly acceptable to [answer your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). This helps others understand that the question has been answered.  Don't for get to [Mark your Answer as Accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/171858).

Comment: Hi Erik. It does not allow to write an answer. We are no longer accepting answers from this account. See the Help Center to learn more.